# complex filters method in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am stuck with a problem where I need to send remainder emails to all users whos training is expiring in some period of time like ratio of 5/6. I have setup a scheduling system it will be filter all training programs who are expiring everyday and send them remainders. The problem I am facing is I am unable to figure out the query.

This is the model I am using:

```
class Training(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('customer.Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trainings')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    presentation = models.FileField(upload_to='trainings')
    data = models.JSONField()
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    released = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_at = models.DateField()
    end_at = models.DateField()
    codes_file = models.FileField(null=True, max_length=1024)
    contact = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_reminded = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is the query I am trying to run.

```
trainings = Training.objects.filter(is_reminded=False, ).annotate(
    deadline=(datetime.today() - F('start_at')).days / (F('start_at') - F('end_at')).days, output_field=DateField()
).filter(deadline__gt=0.833)
```

Error I am getting from this. I understand why this error is coming but I cannot figure out how to pull this data out.

```
Internal Server Error: /testing/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\apaa_backend-tCJa5vIy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\apaa_backend\apaa\testing.py", line 22, in list_deadline_trainings
    deadline=(datetime.today() - F('start_at')).days / (F('start_at') - F('end_at')).days, output_field=DateField()
AttributeError: 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'days'
```

I have tried different solutions to solve this like by annotating a new column using F() but cannot figure out how to solve this query. If anyone can help me out or suggest something helpful I will be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`F` expressions refer to data in the database and get evaluated by the DB. They aren't Python.

You may be able to use [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract), but is a really complicated queryset worth the effort?

If the size of the `Training` table is small enough or the fraction to be reminded large enough, do what filtering you can in the queryset and the rest in Python.

```
trainings = Training.objects.filter(is_reminded=False, )
    # maybe also filter end_at not in the past, start_at not in the future?
for training in trainings:
    deadline = (datetime.today() - training.start_at).days / (
        (training.start_at - training.end_at).days
    if deadline > 0.833:
        #do remind for this training
        training.is_reminded = True
        training.save()
```